# Changing web root folder's location in EasyPHP

Tags: apache-2.2

After following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515553/how-to-change-the-location-of-web-root-folder-of-easyphp)'s answers my web root folder remains the same. This is why I did:

1) Changed `DocumentRoot "${path}/data/localweb"` into `DocumentRoot "${path}/www"`

2) Changed `<Directory "${path}/data/localweb">` into `<Directory "${path}/www">`

Restarted EasyPHP many times, these changes have absolutely no effect in my case. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want your Document Root to be "D:\root".
You basically have to change all occurrences of DocumentRoot, to read as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "D:\root"
```

And all occurrences of Directory to read:

```
<Directory "D:\root">
```

If you want something clearer, post your current configuration so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You are required to change `VirtualHost` and `conf_files\httpd.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "${path}/data/localweb/public_html"
ServerName 127.0.0.1
<Directory "${path}/data/localweb/public_html">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

On windows: configuration->Apache.
(opens `httpd.conf`)

> ```
> DocumentRoot "D:/proot"
> (...)
> ```

```
# DocumentRootDirectory 
<Directory "D:\proot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 (...)
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "D:/proot/"
   ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>`
```

Repalce `D:/proot/` with your path.

Comment: Thanks Overmind, I'm on Windows. Could you make your answer a bit more clear please? For example I don't understand what "Change VirtualHost" means. What lines in what file should be replaced by what lines?